How to write $ssl_client_s_dn check config for multiple CN in NGINX?
I have different certs with CN like
map.lmback.com, gustavo.lmback.com and LMProdusr
So i want to check CN in nginx:
location /api/1.0/alameda {
    set $ssl_client_s_dn "CN=LMProdusr";
    if ($ssl_client_s_dn !~ "(CN=\*\.lmback\.com|CN=LMProdusr)"){
       return 403;
    }

    return 410;
}

And it works.
But
location /api/1.0/alameda {
    set $ssl_client_s_dn "CN=map.lmback.com";
    if ($ssl_client_s_dn !~ "(CN=\*\.lmback\.com|CN=LMProdusr)"){
       return 403;
    }

    return 410;
}

Doesn't work. How to make wildcart in regex for nginx?

Why are you escaping *? In regex it is a quantifier. So, it should be something like: (CN=.*\.lmback\.com|CN=LMProdusr)

Also, the map directive is better suited to matching multiple strings.
